# Lower bound for $a^kb^k$ in one-tape TM

Tags: complexity-theory, formal-languages, time-complexity, automata

For the language
$ L= \{a^kb^k | k \geq 0 \} $
How can i show there is no one-tape Turing Machine that can decide $L$ in less than $O(n\log n)$ time ?

Comment: Have you tried to use the method of crossing sequences?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus If i define $L_n = \{ a^kb^k | n \geq k \geq 0 \}$ and consider crossing sequences between $n+1$ (to include at least one b) and $2n$ , is it good idea to think about ?

Comment: Yes, that's the first step.